# Random seed in animation

Tags: java, random, processing

I'm making an animation in Processing. I have some random points moving randomly and then forming a solid. Since the animation was too slow, I was thinking of saving the frames and then adding them into a movie.

I need to run the same program twice or more, so I'm using the Random class instead of the random() function of Processing, but I dont get the meaning of the seed parameter.

What should I put as seed? Is this random method equally distributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what you put as the seed.  It's actually better to leave it parameterless because then it will choose a different seed every time.  If you specify a seed explicitly, you will receive random behavior... but the *same* random behavior every time you run it!

This is because random number generators are not actually, logically random.  They are pseudorandom because they are produced with an algorithm.  The seed is part of that algorithm.  Basically, the algorithm will produce an even distribution of numbers within the range (in fact, so even that PRNG's are often criticized for not being random *enough*).

> A PRNG can be started from an arbitrary starting state using a seed state. It will always produce the same sequence thereafter when initialized with that state.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Can you give a link or example of a *purely* RNG?  I'd be very interested!  (I thought the laws of scientific determinism precluded this to begin with, haha.)

Comment: Quantum physics lends itself to all kinds of truly random numbers! Classical physics precludes it, but quantum physics doesn't. I wrote an API in Java for the one created by the quantum optics group at the Australian National University, but their public access appears to be either down or no longer working (if it comes back, [click here](http://150.203.48.55/). Public, true RNGs are usually hardware generators connected to the Internet. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Physical_phenomena_with_quantum-random_properties).

Comment: sorry, just to be sure I get this straight: using `new Random()` with no parameters will get me the same behaviour if I run it two times? or do I need to set the seed in this case?

Comment: Nope!  As detailed in @linski 's answer, the default constructor for `Random` will give you a different seed every time.  So you will always get completely different (although evenly-distributed) behavior.

Comment: Exactly what @Jeff said. The only time you'll get the same numbers is if _you_ specify the same seed every time, like using `new Random(100)`. The default constructor uses time in nanoseconds alongside a sort of salt, so it's highly unlikely to give you the same seed twice.

Comment: Example of a quantum, hardware TRNG: http://www.idquantique.com/true-random-number-generator/products-overview.html --This one isn't connected to the Internet, ofc, it's plugged into your machine (albeit at a very high price), but you get the idea. They exist :)

Comment: That's very cool.  Now that you say it, I've actually heard of this before, and it really makes me want to launch into a discussion/debate about quantum physics and determinism... (Too bad this isn't the place.)  Thanks a lot for the links!  My reading material for the rest of the day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

it'll get you different seed almost every time. Don't know if it is enough, but better than constant seed definetly.

Though, when you do new Random()

```
 public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
```

this is what happens so I suggest you try a bit, which is better for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [JavaDoc's for the Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) you will see that you need to call specific methods, nextInt(), nextFloat(), etc. to get uniform or gaussian distribution. If you want your results to be repeatable you should use a constant value for the seed. Otherwise if you want the results to vary each time it is run, I agree that the time is a good way to seed it.